# Java play two responses from one request

Tags: java, playframework, request, response

I have a request to update data in my server.

When I **update the data**, I need to run a very **heavy** calculation that takes 10-30 seconds.

I want to do this:

1. Send request to update from client
2. Get the request in server and start a *new thread* to do the calculation, then update the object in my database and return a response to the client that the update is complete.
3. When the calculation ends - send another response to the client informing him that the calculation ended.

That way we have 2 update information sent to the client.

Comment: What is "some time"? 30 seconds? 5 hours?

Comment: The time is about 10-30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes you should have 2 entries :

- one route that does the update to the database (Lets call it Controller.updateTheDatabase())
- one route that does the heavy calculation (Lets call it
  Controller.doHeavyCalculation())

(without context it's hard to give good names)

Then you define each one of those functions in your **Controller**,

1. doHeavyCalculation: calls your calculation Service asynchronously
2. updateTheDatabase: sends a database update asynchronously

Once you have this, you can call your API in your template, and you use the 2 responses `separately`(I do with with AJAX JavaScript) to update the information messages.

I use PlayFramework with Scala so sorry if I cannot help with chunks of code but I ran into problems similar to yours.

Here is [the documentation for Asynchronous requests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync)

EDIT : After reading the question again I changed my approach

Comment: Thnx alot! I tried this but, when i return the first result ( the update - true (completed) ) i returned so i cant go on and send again the response from the calculation

Comment: Got it! Thnx alot :)), my problem was doing it only from server. Thank you :D